# RelativeLayout with vertical centered at right

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I do this simple layout with a RelativeLayout?

```
--------------------------------
First line
                           9999
Second line
--------------------------------
```

Two things:

- Between "First line" and "Second line" there is no a space line.
- The number "9999" is aligned at the right and vertical centered.

I tried this, but doesn't work

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/second_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="26dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Second Line" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/first_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/second_line"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="First line"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_line"
    android:text="99999" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is the `android:layout_centerVertical` because in a `RelativeLayout` you can't use a normal `android:layout_gravity`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/first_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="First line" />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/second_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first_line"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Second Line" />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="99999" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/first_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="First line"
     />
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first_line"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="99999" />

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/second_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="26dip" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Second Line" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The space in between the first and second line isn't desired right?

Comment: Yes, this solution is great except for the fact that there are three lines instead of two (both left texts have to be together, one at the top of the other one, and the number at right centered vertically)... do you know how to solve that issue? :(

Answer (score 0):

Your 9999 text view and either your first line or second line need to be in a horizontal layout of their own.  By declaring them each separately you are making things harder on yourself.  You can align them in a similar manner using tags that are native to a relative layout but I find it easier to just declare them in groups.  I.E. surround the two items that you want to have aligned in a horizontal layout.

Comment: The thing is that this layout is going to be used inside a huge ListView, so I need a layout as much optimized as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Basically inside the RelativeLayout which is a ViewGroup btw, put another LinearLayout (with an id so you can reference it) and use that to setup layout. Treat LinearLayout as just another element in the RelativeLayout. So as a general principal you can use Layouts just like other view items. Inside the activity you can even reference them LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutId);

or treat it as a

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutId).
```

A layout is a type of View. A ViewGroup.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
 android:padding="6dip"
  android:gravity="center_vertical">
 <LinearLayout ..... android:id="@+id/linearLayoutId" android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView  
android:id="@+id/second_line"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="26dip" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:text="Second Line" />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/first_line"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_above="@id/second_line"
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:text="First line"
android:gravity="center_vertical" />
<LinearLayout>
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/number"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayoutId"
android:text="99999" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then something in text view on rigth for centering.  Checkout center_vertical etc. You can also combine aligning left/rigth and centervertical.

Comment: I'm trying to do it only with a RelativeLayout. I know that with the LinearLayout is easier, but I need to do this layout as much optimized as I can